# How to execute mocha unit test cases synchronously?

Tags: unit-testing, mocha.js, synchronous

I want to execute mocha unit test cases as synchronous . this is my code

```
 describe('curd',function()
{
  it('create',function(){

   });

  it('delete',function(){

  });

});
```

is it possible that execute the delete test case once create is done ?
If it is possible then how to use ?
Please let me know ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you declare a `done` parameter, Mocha will pass in a callback function and wait until it's called before running the next test.

```
it('works', function (done) {
  // ...
  done();
});
```

I guess that is what you want. This is actually making the test "asynchronous", because the next test case is not called immediately after the previous returned. The default is "synchronous".

You can also use `done` in `before`, `after`, `beforeEach` and `afterEach` as well. If you pass an argument to the done function, it will make your test case fail.